# Union, Intersection, Difference, etc. of different types of languages

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, closure-properties

I am preparing for a competitive exam (GATE) in which questions are asked in Automata about operations among different types of languages. For example,

> If $L_1$ is recursive & $L_2$ is recursively enumerable, then is $L_1\cap L_2$ recursively enumerable?

Similarly,

> If $L_1$ is regular, $L_2$ is a deterministic CFL and $L_3$ is recursively enumerable, then is $L_1 \cap L_2$ a deterministic CFL? Is $L_3 \cap L_1$ recursive? Is $L_1 \cup L_2$ context free? etc.

Now I can compare such operations between languages of the same type using closure properties, but how do I tackle such questions?

Comment: You either memorize the answers, or determine the answer on a case by case basis. In most cases either you can immediately see why the result is necessarily of type X, or it is not necessarily of type X.

Comment: Questions are never repeated in this exam. So, memorizing is useless. I need to know the exact technique of how to tackle such questions.

Comment: The technique is, try to prove that the result is of type X, and if you can't do it, try to construct a counterexample. Some practice can help you with these steps.

Comment: And how do I compute the result X? There are no language definitions given in the question.

Comment: By "the result" I meant $L_1 \cap L_2$ in your first example, $L_3 \cap L_2$ in your second, and $L_1 \cup L_2$ in your third.

Comment: The answer is to understand what it means for, e.g., a language to be recursive. If you understand that, you can figure out whether the intersection/union/difference/whatever of two recursive languages is also recursive. There is no "exact proof technique".

Comment: @David That's not entirely true. There is one "proof technique" which helps in many situations. If you have two machines of the same class, you can trivially "union" them as a non-deterministic machine of that class. To "intersect" two machines, you can form the Cartesian product machine, however that machine may not be in the same class. It is for DFAs, but not for PDAs, because the Cartesian product machine has two stacks. This does prove that the intersection of two regular languages is regular, and it suggests (but doesn't prove) that the intersection of two CFLs may not be a CFL.

Comment: @Pseudonym That's already two proof techniques! (Nondeterminism and Cartesian product.) And, as you say, they don't directly apply to PDAs.

Comment: Nondeterminism applies to nondeterministic PDAs, of course.

Comment: I do not need to prove. I will get about 2 minutes for every question on the exam. The questions are of multiple choice type but it is impossible to guess. Also, they can pick any combination of languages from the Chomsky hierarchy and apply any operation and ask what the result would be.

So I believe there must be some short-cut formula or concept using closure properties, else they wouldn't ask such questions in the exam.